# Turf toe taping and toe joint protection

Tags: toe

There are [multiple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icdm2Za6w08) [similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mUuX-awUxs) [suggestions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icdm2Za6w08) on how to tape a turf toe. It roughly looks something like the image below and is done with kinesiotape.

[image]

From a layman's perspective it seems like the goal of the taping is to prevent excessive extension of the toe. It doesn't deal with trying to protect the toe join (which to be frank isn't clear how to do with tape).

My question is why isn't there equal focus on preventing the force from the weight being excreted on the toe joint while walking equally important?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read about "turf toe", and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.